# sql query for accumulated value calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing some design and logic issues in generating correct method/query for the below requirement.

My primary table is

select * from [table] where ID='XYZ'

[image]

Now i have calculate the accumulated riskweight by as following requirement for this i need to write a logic

**conditions:**

for each month in the same year

if(Jan) -> sum of RiskCategory weights in Jan of the same year

if(Feb) --> sum of RiskCategory weights in Jan and Feb of the same year

if(March)-- > sum of RiskCategory weights from Jan to March of the same year

if(April) --> sum of RiskCategory weights from Jan to April of the same year

.

.

.

if(Dec) --> sum of RiskCategory weights from January to December of the same year

**if multiple RiskCategories existed for any month then

case 1. if values are same then take only one value.

case 2: if not same take the maximum among them.

For example if we want to calculate riskweight for the month of November in 2016 then we should consider the below rows only

[image]

** since I do not have data from January to September in 2016 i have considered only October and November data for November month calculation

now the result should be

0.649 for Cardiovascular (case 1)+

1.037 for Pulmonary (case 2)+

0.666 for Diabetes type 2 +

0.798 for Psychiatric +

1.896 for Renal +

0.536 constant = 5.582

and the final result table should be

[image]

please check sqlfiddle for this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8448e/6 [updated]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d05fe/1

Comment: You'll need to do CASE WHEN Month='January' then SUM(Riskweight) logic. You will need to do GROUPING for each Month and YEAR

Comment: Thanks for your input even if go with CASE condition, there is still a part of requirement left, i should consider the risk_category column which should remove the duplicate categories (consider maximum value of that riskcategory for only once). Can you please look at example given for November in my question

Comment: If possible, I'd get all data from your db and do the max/summation logic in code. Keeps the queries performant  and easy to understand.

Comment: please check at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d05fe/1

Comment: @OP, for the maximum logic, do a JOIN on the same table where you look for the Select MAX(RiskWeight). RiskCategory, Month, Year From table GROUP BY RiskCategory, Month, Year. Use this value as to your SUM() query. Make sure you convert your RiskWeight to Decimal. If they are being stored as VARCHAR, you won't have the right output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input @Isaiah3015 my risk_weight column stored as decimal only. and the query is not giving any maximum value. all values still be existed after I use JOIN with the same table using MAX. I would like you clarify one thing here. let say for November 2016 risk_weight i should consider all the risk categories from January to November in 2017 then consider distinct risk_Categories which has the maximum risk weight then have to do the SUM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it right you actually want this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Year,
    Month,
    RiskWeight = SUM(MaxRiskweight) + 0.536
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.ID,
        t1.Year,
        t1.Month,
        t2.RiskCategory,
        MaxRiskweight = MAX(t2.Riskwight)
    FROM
        inputTable AS t1
        JOIN inputTable AS t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND
           t1.Year = t2.Year AND
           t2.Month <= t1.Month
    GROUP BY
        t1.ID,
        t1.Year,
        t1.Month,
        t2.RiskCategory
    ) AS MaxRiskWeights
--WHERE
--  ID = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Year,
    Month
```

I commented the `WHERE` clause out because I suppose you want to calculate it for each `ID` in your table. The constant `0.536` is added to each summarized row of the `RiskWeight`, as you gave it in the example.

Comment: Thanks @Mislav Zic. you are correct the query you have given is calculating riskweights by by month of each year. but if you take decemeber 2016 it has to take all the riskcategories from Jan16 to Dec16 then take the distict maximum values of riskcategories and sum +0.536. so for december the final risk weight will be 5.582 so can you please suggest what needs to change in the query to get this output. Please refer result table(required output without adding 0.536) in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8448e/13

Comment: In your sample data, for the 3/2017 there are only Cardiovascular and Pulmonary risks, but for the 2/2017 there also exists Diabetes Type 2 risk besides those two. So, the calculation for the 3/2017 should include the Diabetes Type 2 as well as Cardiovascular and Pulmonary?

Comment: For 3/2017 we should consider all the 3 categories that means Diabetes Type 2 as well as Cardiovascular and Pulmonary

Comment: I also updated the question to get the clarity thank you very much

Comment: I updated the query. Now it includes maximum risk weighs for all risks up to the current month in each year. The last table with final results in your question is misleading, namely months 12/2016 and 3/2017: it's contradictory to what you said it should have all risks from previous months included.

Comment: Btw, in your test sample (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8448e/13) you swapped years for months and vice versa, i.e. months are 2016 & 2017, and years are actually months. :)

Comment: Fantastic. Its working. thanks a lot for the help. I didn't thought of self join. And I changed the months and year correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions for this.  I believe you essentially want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(riskweight) over (partition by id, year, riskcategory
                             order by month
                            ) as accum_riskweight
from t;
```

This doesn't quite work, because you have the month names -- and these will be ordered alphabetically.  SQL Server is pretty good about converting dates, so this should work:

```
select t.*,
       sum(riskweight) over (partition by year, riskcategory
                             order by convert(date, month + ' 01 2000')
                            ) as accum_riskweight
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed my question. actually my table has month numbers only for understanding purpose i just displayed month names in the question. And also please consider risk_category requirement i have explained this by taking November month example in my question. As i have millions of records in DB writing function to calculate it is not a good option

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct id, year,month,SUM(riskweight) group by  ID,year,month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sum with windowing function as below:

```
Select *, RiskWeight = Sum(Riskwight) over (Partition by Id, [Year] order by [Month]) 
 from (
 Select Id, [Year], [Month], RiskWight = Sum(riskWight) from inputtable
    Group by Id, [Year], [Month]
    ) a
order by [year], [Month]
```

But here [Month] order by with happen in different order as in alphabetical, It is better to have Month Number in this place

Comment: Thanks for your input I have tried the partition concept and tried with month number also but there is still a part of requirement left, i should consider the risk_category column which should remove the duplicate categories (consider maximum value of that riskcategory for only once). Can you please look at example given for November in my question

Comment: Can you please rpovide your input data in text instead of image?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d05fe/1 I have created the sqlfiddle for it. please check

Comment: Updated my query can you check

Comment: Thanks again. I am not sure what is the use of summing in inner query. for the query that you have given the calculated riskweights are incorrect for December 2016 and March 2017. Please check the fiddle updated one with result table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8448e/5

Comment: Hi @kannan any suggestion to meet the requirements

Comment: Your requirement does not have clarity, for RiskWight calculation in xyz, year 2016 month 10 is not added to month 11 whereas month 11 is added to 12 why? On what criteria?

Comment: I am sorry for making confusion here. In the above November example there are two occurrences of  'Cardiovascular' and 'Pulmonary' in riskcategory(by considering all the riskcategories from jan16 to Nove16 for nov16 riskwieght calculation). so now we have to consider only one occurence which has ma riskweight value. so for november 2016( (Pulmonary)1.037+ Cardiovascular (0.649)
) )  here for  the November. please do let me know if you need more clarity. I can change the table and will explain with better example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150743/discussion-between-user2293819-and-kannan-kandasamy).

Comment: Thank you. I opened the chat window to discuss.